# What are the specific vulnerabilities of large-index tracking ETFs to sudden market moves such as crashes?

Tags: etf

For instance, are tracking errors likely to increase during a financial/market crash and thus pose a risk to ETF investors who count on effective replication of the underlying index at all times ?

Answer (score 3):

Crashes are highly unlikely.  We've had two in the past 100 years (1929 and 1987).  The rest of the drops have been large corrections and bear markets.  Assuming that you meant the latter,   the disconnect will occur if there's high volatility.

It's likely that the index ETFs trade down faster than the component stocks and even if it's the other way around, the  spread between the two will widen  and there will be arbitrage opportunities.  The big players such as floor traders, hedge funds, investment bank trading desks and authorized participants will step in to take advantage of these.  Maybe these players effectively control the  widening differential, maybe not but for the average long term buy and hold investor, it's meaningless.  He will be paralyzed by fear, riding his investment down, hoping that a bottom is put in so that he can begin to recover (see down 50% in 2000 and 2008).  It won't make a difference to him if the large index ETF is tracking at 100% or not.

An an aside, I experienced the 1987 crash. Equity prices were much lower then, for the most part under $100, unlike today when a stock with a price of several hundred dollars isn't unusual. This was before decimalization.  Stocks that normally traded with 1/8 or 1/4 point B/A spreads had spreads several dollars wide.  Price was moving so fast that a quote was stale almost by the time that you heard it (online trading did not exist as we know it today).  If that were to occur again, few retail investors would participate on the sell side other than those who can't take the pain anymore, plus some buyers with a brass set.  With such wide B/A spreads, both will be screwed on execution price.  Tracking error is likely to be a lesser problem.

The short answer? IMO, the specific vulnerability of   investors in a deep correction or bear market will be loss of portfolio value.  Marginal tracking disparities between ETF price and component price won't be their major problem.  Getting fair value might be.

Comment: Thanks. I should have used the term "speculator" and not "investor", as I was thinking about the use of out of the money puts to bet on a massive downturn in the SPX, and those puts mechanically cost 10 times more than corresponding SPY (ETF) puts, which I would therefore prefer buying. I was thus wondering whether the SPX and SPY could diverge significantly during a sudden and large downturn, including something of the 1929/1987 type, or, more probably, a sustained week or month-long downturn.

Comment: Just my opinion but I don't think that there will be a major divergence b/t SPX and SPY in a correction.  Your concern during a sudden and large downturn should be capturing delta not arbitrage. If you are fortunate enough to be in a position where you have profitable long puts, focus on money management. Possibilities include rolling long puts down, selling further OTM inflated put IV, converting long puts to strangles, etc. IMO, you want to book gains or lock in some of the gains while retaining the ability to profit on add'l market moves, whether they be up or down. The drop won't be linear